# DocuSign and NetSuite webhook event notification auth

Tags: netsuite, docusignapi

I've written a NetSuite solution that creates a DocuSign envelope from NetSuite.  I now need to be notified when the envelope is completed.  I'm writing a NetSuite RESTlet to process the DocuSign webhook.  NetSuite requires authentication for external clients (such as DocuSign).  How do I pass the credentials/header for DocuSign to use in the event_notification?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could store the token inside the envelope in custom text fields. There is a limit of 100 character per field so you may need to break the token into many such fields to do that. 
Note that the connect webHook call gives you a lot of information including potentially the completed document itself. So this may be another way to do this.